# Convert QTP Object repository (*.tsr) file to other format

Tags: qtp

I have a QTP Object repository in .tsr format which i want in convert in other formats like XML or YAML or .properties or excel or any other format which i can easily read from java.

Is any any API or tool that can assist me in doing that??

Answer (score 1):

QTP  allows exporting Shared Object Repositories from the Object Repository Manager. Just select `File` -> `Export to XML`.

Comment: Thanks for this..But actually what i am interested in is - I have a QTP project and now client wants us to navigate the entire proj to Selenium.There are 2 options  1) Convert/rescript all QTP scripts to Selenium format   2) Use some kind of Stub/API etc so as to execute the QTP scripts from Selenium without using QTP atall.

Comment: @user1677944, that's another question altogether, why didn't you ask it to begin with?